# How to create a date sequence for 10 years with 16 Day interval with each year starts with 1st January

Tags: r, datetime

Following code create a date sequence of 10 years with 16 Day interval.

```
library(chron)
seq.dates("01/01/2008","12/31/2017", 16)
```

Output

```
[1] 01/01/08 01/17/08 02/02/08 02/18/08 03/05/08 03/21/08 04/06/08 04/22/08 05/08/08 
[10] 05/24/08 06/09/08 06/25/08 07/11/08 07/27/08 08/12/08 08/28/08 09/13/08 09/29/08
[19] 10/15/08 10/31/08 11/16/08 12/02/08 12/18/08 **01/03/09** 01/19/09 02/04/09 02/20/09
[28] 03/08/09 03/24/09 04/09/09 04/25/09 05/11/09 ..........
........................
...........................
[208] 01/25/17 02/10/17 02/26/17 03/14/17 03/30/17 04/15/17 05/01/17 05/17/17 06/02/17
[217] 06/18/17 07/04/17 07/20/17 08/05/17 08/21/17 09/06/17 09/22/17 10/08/17 10/24/17
[226] 11/09/17 11/25/17 12/11/17 12/27/17
```

I want first entry for every year to be 1st January not the day which comes after 16 days from the last entry of previous year (BOLD entry in the example sequence) and subsequent entries accordingly.

A long way to do this would be creating date sequence for individual years separately then merging them in  a single vector. I'm curious that is there any way to do this in a single line code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this work for you. Uses sapply to pass a vector of starting points and then makes `seq.dates` do more limited sequences. The `sapply` function will simplify to an array if possible.

```
dates(sapply( seq.dates("01/01/2008", "01/01/2017", by="years") ,
                               function(x) seq.dates(x, to=x+365, by=16, length=23)))
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]    
 [1,] 01/01/08 01/01/09 01/01/10 01/01/11 01/01/12 01/01/13 01/01/14 01/01/15
 [2,] 01/17/08 01/17/09 01/17/10 01/17/11 01/17/12 01/17/13 01/17/14 01/17/15
 [3,] 02/02/08 02/02/09 02/02/10 02/02/11 02/02/12 02/02/13 02/02/14 02/02/15
 [4,] 02/18/08 02/18/09 02/18/10 02/18/11 02/18/12 02/18/13 02/18/14 02/18/15
 [5,] 03/05/08 03/06/09 03/06/10 03/06/11 03/05/12 03/06/13 03/06/14 03/06/15
 [6,] 03/21/08 03/22/09 03/22/10 03/22/11 03/21/12 03/22/13 03/22/14 03/22/15
 [7,] 04/06/08 04/07/09 04/07/10 04/07/11 04/06/12 04/07/13 04/07/14 04/07/15
 [8,] 04/22/08 04/23/09 04/23/10 04/23/11 04/22/12 04/23/13 04/23/14 04/23/15
 [9,] 05/08/08 05/09/09 05/09/10 05/09/11 05/08/12 05/09/13 05/09/14 05/09/15
[10,] 05/24/08 05/25/09 05/25/10 05/25/11 05/24/12 05/25/13 05/25/14 05/25/15
[11,] 06/09/08 06/10/09 06/10/10 06/10/11 06/09/12 06/10/13 06/10/14 06/10/15
[12,] 06/25/08 06/26/09 06/26/10 06/26/11 06/25/12 06/26/13 06/26/14 06/26/15
[13,] 07/11/08 07/12/09 07/12/10 07/12/11 07/11/12 07/12/13 07/12/14 07/12/15
[14,] 07/27/08 07/28/09 07/28/10 07/28/11 07/27/12 07/28/13 07/28/14 07/28/15
[15,] 08/12/08 08/13/09 08/13/10 08/13/11 08/12/12 08/13/13 08/13/14 08/13/15
[16,] 08/28/08 08/29/09 08/29/10 08/29/11 08/28/12 08/29/13 08/29/14 08/29/15
[17,] 09/13/08 09/14/09 09/14/10 09/14/11 09/13/12 09/14/13 09/14/14 09/14/15
[18,] 09/29/08 09/30/09 09/30/10 09/30/11 09/29/12 09/30/13 09/30/14 09/30/15
[19,] 10/15/08 10/16/09 10/16/10 10/16/11 10/15/12 10/16/13 10/16/14 10/16/15
[20,] 10/31/08 11/01/09 11/01/10 11/01/11 10/31/12 11/01/13 11/01/14 11/01/15
[21,] 11/16/08 11/17/09 11/17/10 11/17/11 11/16/12 11/17/13 11/17/14 11/17/15
[22,] 12/02/08 12/03/09 12/03/10 12/03/11 12/02/12 12/03/13 12/03/14 12/03/15
[23,] 12/18/08 12/19/09 12/19/10 12/19/11 12/18/12 12/19/13 12/19/14 12/19/15
      [,9]     [,10]   
 [1,] 01/01/16 01/01/17
 [2,] 01/17/16 01/17/17
 [3,] 02/02/16 02/02/17
 [4,] 02/18/16 02/18/17
 [5,] 03/05/16 03/06/17
 [6,] 03/21/16 03/22/17
 [7,] 04/06/16 04/07/17
 [8,] 04/22/16 04/23/17
 [9,] 05/08/16 05/09/17
[10,] 05/24/16 05/25/17
[11,] 06/09/16 06/10/17
[12,] 06/25/16 06/26/17
[13,] 07/11/16 07/12/17
[14,] 07/27/16 07/28/17
[15,] 08/12/16 08/13/17
[16,] 08/28/16 08/29/17
[17,] 09/13/16 09/14/17
[18,] 09/29/16 09/30/17
[19,] 10/15/16 10/16/17
[20,] 10/31/16 11/01/17
[21,] 11/16/16 11/17/17
[22,] 12/02/16 12/03/17
[23,] 12/18/16 12/19/17
```

I was a bit surprised at this result since I thought the value would be a character matrix, but `str` shows it's a matrix of chron date elements. Can remove the apparent "matrix" (actually "dates" with a dimension attribute) structure with a call to `c`:

```
str(c(dates(sapply( seq.dates("01/01/2008", "01/01/2017", by="years") , function(x) seq.dates(x, to=x+365, by=16, length=23))) ))
 'dates' num [1:230] 01/01/08 01/17/08 02/02/08 02/18/08 03/05/08 ...
 - attr(*, "format")= chr "m/d/y"
 - attr(*, "origin")= num [1:3] 1 1 1970
```